# Inserting Contents Of Text File Into HTML

Tags: php, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Say I've got a .txt file that looks something like this:

**heyo.txt:**

```
<p>heyo</p><p>heyo!</p>
```

If I want the contents of **heyo.txt** rendered somewhere on the inside of a View (say, after the view is done loading), then how do I go about doing that?

Is there a way to accomplish this in ASP.NET in a way that is similar to PHP's readfile() function?  I've tried using Response.WriteFile with no success:

```
@{ Response.ContentType = "text/html"; //(and "text/xml")
   Response.WriteFile(Url.Content("~/Content/heyo.txt"));
 }
```

Using "text/html" replaces the entire page with the contents of heyo.txt, and "text/xml" throws `"XML Parsing Error: junk after document element"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of accomplishing this in ASP.NET MVC, is to do this in the controller instead with a [`FileResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.118).aspx) using the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx) method of the controller.

For example:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return File("~/Content/heyo.txt", "text/html");
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!  What's the general reason that Response.WriteFile doesn't work here?

Comment: @alex [Well-formed XML documents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document) may only have one root element. If you had `<body><p>heyo</p><p>heyo!</p></body>` I suspect it would work as expected.